# Get counts of JSONB properties

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have jsonb column `answers` which may look like this for a 3 rows:

```
{answer1: {label: "", value: "answer1_value1"}, answer2: {label: "", value: "answer2_value1"}}
{answer1: {label: "", value: "answer1_value2"}, answer2: {label: "", value: "answer2_value1"}}
{answer1: {label: "", value: "answer1_value2"}, answer2: {label: "", value: "answer2_value2"}}
```

Answer properties names can be different for a set of rows. I want to get this result(count for each answer grouped by value) from the example above:

```
answer1: { answer1_value1: 1, answer1_value2: 2}
answer2: { answer2_value1: 2, answer2_value2: 1}
```

Is it possible?

I got field names like this `SELECT DISTINCT json_object_keys(answers::json) as field`, but do not know what can I do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_each()` to be able to count answers and aggregate the results back into a json object:

```
select jsonb_build_object(key, jsonb_object_agg(val, count))
from (
    select key, value->>'value' as val, count(*)
    from my_table
    cross join jsonb_each(answers) 
    group by key, val
    ) s
group by key;
```

[Working example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/JGVZ61668)

Comment: I guess this is what I need, thanks! Sometimes db contains `[]` in the answers field. Could you tell how to omit such fields? And I want to put one condition `WHERE event_id=<Id>` but this leads to `field name must not be null` error. How this can be fixed?

Comment: Hard to say without the model and sample erroneous data. Please, use [rextester](https://rextester.com/) to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the issues.

Comment: Sure, edited your example. In extester event_id condition works, but array fields break everything.

Comment: I cannot see the changes, need a link to a forked example.

Comment: Add the condition `jsonb_typeof(answers) = 'object'` [rextester](https://rextester.com/BBFDDQ64690)